# how do i know A compiler basic datatype how large they are?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded, embedded-linux, elf

i was using arm-none-eabi-readelf -h test.o analizes a object file,it give me
Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
Entry point address:               0x0
i go to the souce code of the arm-none-eabi-readelf ，but i can't figure out how large the datetype is,long,int,short.some answers say there limit.h can find some define,finally i analized long is 4B,int 4B short 2B (personally opinion)

```c
 /* ELF Header */
#define EI_NIDENT   16      /* Size of e_ident[] */
typedef struct elf_internal_ehdr {
  unsigned char     e_ident[EI_NIDENT]; /* ELF "magic number" */           //16B
  bfd_vma       e_entry;/* Entry point virtual address */  //unsigned long but 4B
  bfd_size_type     e_phoff;/* Program header table file offset */ //unsigned long  but4B
  bfd_size_type     e_shoff;/* Section header table file offset */    //unsigned long  but4B
  unsigned long     e_version;/* Identifies object file version */    //unsigned long  but4B
  unsigned long     e_flags;/* Processor-specific flags */          //unsigned long  but4B
  unsigned short    e_type;     /* Identifies object file type */         //2B
  unsigned short    e_machine;  /* Specifies required architecture */        //2B
  unsigned int      e_ehsize;   /* ELF header size in bytes */             //   4B
  unsigned int      e_phentsize;    /* Program header table entry size */      //   4B
  unsigned int      e_phnum;    /* Program header table entry count */       //   4B
  unsigned int      e_shentsize;    /* Section header table entry size */      //     4B
  unsigned int      e_shnum;    /* Section header table entry count */    //       4B
  unsigned int      e_shstrndx; /* Section header string table index */   //         4B
} Elf_Internal_Ehdr;
```

but total doesn't fit Size of this header:               52 (bytes)

is there any method can figure out basic datatype how many bytes they are except sizeof()(cross compiler i don't know how to use it to printf sizof() result )

Comment: That why one should include `<stdint.h>` and use the standard [fixed-width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer). The structure you see is badly programmed, for an era before 64-bit systems (and maybe even before the standard integer types were introduced in the C99 standard).

Comment: As for finding out the size of integer types, you need to know the target architecture and then read the compiler documentation to find out the sizes for the specific compiler/target combination.

Comment: With GCC and Clang, you can do this using the `__asm__` construct with an immediate operand. When the code `void foo(void) { __asm__("# The size of int is %c0." : : "i" (sizeof (int))); }` is compiled with the `-S` switch to generate assembly, a line such as “ ##The size of int is 4.” will appear in the generated assembly file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question. You asked what's the size of `unsigned long` in some unspecified environment. But you actually want to know the size of the fields in an ELF file. This information is present on Wikipedia.

For example, [the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) says `e_version` needs to be 32 bits wide. So you should use `uint32_t` for `e_version`.

Don't forget to tell your compiler to not use any padding for this structure if you plan to `memcpy` from an ELF file into it.

Comment: `e_ident[EI_DATA]`, yes. It's up to you to reverse the bytes when appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The Linux [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) answers your question.

It defines types as :

```
           ElfN_Addr       Unsigned program address, uintN_t
           ElfN_Off        Unsigned file offset, uintN_t
           ElfN_Section    Unsigned section index, uint16_t
           ElfN_Versym     Unsigned version symbol information, uint16_t
           Elf_Byte        unsigned char
           ElfN_Half       uint16_t
           ElfN_Sword      int32_t
           ElfN_Word       uint32_t
           ElfN_Sxword     int64_t
           ElfN_Xword      uint64_t
```

And all those types have clear fixed sizes. `ElfN_Addr` and `ElfN_Off` are `uint64_t` if your target system is 64 bits or `uint32_t` for 32 bits systems

The elf header is defined as :

```
           #define EI_NIDENT 16

           typedef struct {
               unsigned char e_ident[EI_NIDENT];
               uint16_t      e_type;
               uint16_t      e_machine;
               uint32_t      e_version;
               ElfN_Addr     e_entry;
               ElfN_Off      e_phoff;
               ElfN_Off      e_shoff;
               uint32_t      e_flags;
               uint16_t      e_ehsize;
               uint16_t      e_phentsize;
               uint16_t      e_phnum;
               uint16_t      e_shentsize;
               uint16_t      e_shnum;
               uint16_t      e_shstrndx;
           } ElfN_Ehdr;
```

Do not reinvent the wheel. Use standard  `elf.h` header (for example https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/elf.h)